# Using python how can I register specific mapping definition?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the [elasticsearch-py docs](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html) I can't find an example registering a mapping, which performs what these REST API [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping) say:

The put mapping API allows to register specific mapping definition for a specific type.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping' -d '
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing anything with the index involves the Indices APIs. PUTing mapping is also one of many Indices API. They can be found in the `Indices` section under `API Documentation` of the Python client docs.

And you need [this: put_mapping(*args, **kwargs)](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
def fMap(document_type):
    mapping={document_type:{\
             "properties":{\
             "a_field":{"type":"integer","store":"yes"},\
             "other_field": {"type":"string","index":"analyzed","store":"no"},\
             "title":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index": "analyzed","term_vector":"yes","similarity":"BM25"},\
             "content":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index":  "analyzed","term_vector": "yes","similarity":"BM25"}\
             }}}
    return mapping
def dSetting(nShards,nReplicas):
    dSetting={
    "settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":nShards,"number_of_replicas":nReplicas}},\
    "analysis":{\
        "filter":{\
        "my_english":{"type":"english","stopwords_path":"english.txt"},\
        "english_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","language":"english"}},\
        "analyzer":{"english":{"filter":["lowercase","my_english","english_stemmer"]}}}}
    return dSetting
def EsSetup(con,idx,docType,dset,mapping):
    con.indices.delete(index=idx,ignore=[400, 404])
    con.indices.create(index=idx,body=dset,ignore=400)
    con.indices.put_mapping(index=idx,doc_type=docType,body=mapping)

conEs=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200,'timeout':180}])
dMap = fMap('docTypeName')
dSet = dSetting(8,1)
EsSetup(conEs,'idxName','docTypeName',dset,dMap)
```